# Why do I get an error in my HTML canvas in this asp.net program?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to put an `HTML CANVAS` in my website.

This is my code Lines but I have an error

> "CS1026: ) exepted"

and I don't really know why.

```
 <asp:TableCell  runat="server" onload="init();" >
      <canvas id="canvas"  width="640" height="480" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
      <%--<object width="640" height="480"><embed src="../Images/Animations/animation-pharmacie.swf" width="640" height="480" /></object>--%>
 </asp:TableCell>
```

Comment: please paste init definition

Comment: `onload="init"` try this may help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help , but it doesn't work :/